# Can I add javascript dynamically to an existing script element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to dynamically add javascript to an existing script element something like:

```
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
se.innerHTML = 'alert(1)';
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(se);
```

The interesting part is `se.innerHTML = 'alert(1)';` and if it is valid? If not how can I do this the right way?

Comment: I tried it, after adding the `<script>` element for the first time (with `document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(se);`), it executes, but it doesn't respond to any further `.innerHTML` changes, you will have to add another `<script>` element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not adding JavaScript to an existing script element, it's creating a new script element and adding it to the document.

This does work in modern browsers, but you wouldn't normally do it unless you had some code in a variable that you really needed to execute in global context (so you couldn't use `new Function()`, or `eval` from inside a function).

What's the use case? Do you *really* have to do this?

If you did try to change the script's content by writing to the text content of a `<script>` that was already in the document, it would not cause the new script content to be run, it would just change the contents of the DOM. The exact circumstances of what causes new script to be run when a `<script>` element is manipulated vary from browser to browser (though HTML5 is [trying](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-script-block-s-type) to standardise it); for now it is better to avoid doing anything other than simply creating and appending a new script. (And even better to avoid scripting `<script>` at all, if possible.)

Setting `innerHTML` will work; RoToRa's method with `createTextNode` is better though. For `<script>` in an old-school-HTML document, `innerHTML` will actually do the same thing as `createTextNode`, since `<script>` is a CDATA element which cannot contain markup. It would matter for XHTML-served-as-XML though, and in general it is cleaner to avoid `innerHTML` and its escaping problems when you just want to set plain text.

Also, you can use `[0]` instead of `item(0)` (this is defined as part of the JavaScript DOM bindings), and you should in general avoid `getAttribute`/`setAttribute`; use the DOM HTML properties like `se.type=...` instead, which are more readable and less buggy in IE (though the IE bugs wouldn't affect you for the `type` attribute).

Comment: +1 eval seems the logical way to do this.  However, be very suspicious about evalling just anything that comes from the server.

Comment: +1 for asking for the use case and the suggestions in the last paragraph.

Comment: +1 @bobince , related question. if the interpreter has already passed the `head` section , and later , at the end of `body` , I create new `script` element and append it to the `head` - it still runs the script ( even if async=false). which leads me to ask : does script are handled differently ? (I mean - the Head section was already digested and still the future appended script - still runs) http://jsbin.com/EraMuKE/15/edit

Comment: @Royi: yes, the script gets run on injection anywhere into the DOM. (Though what counts as the active DOM is slightly different across browsers, the document `<head>` works consistently.) There is not necessarily any coherent thinking behind why this works that way. Script insertion was not a deliberately designed feature, it's just what IE did and others copied (IE being the first browser to implement the fully-interactive DOM as we know it).

Comment: tnx What  do you mean by "active dom" ?

Comment: In some browsers the script only executes when inserted into a node that is a descendent of the page's document. IIRC in IE inserting into a disconnected node still executes the script.

Answer (score 25):

All browsers currently support a javascript **text** property, and will evaluate the text when a new script element (without a src attribute) is added to the document.

innerHTML or adding child nodes to a script element do not evaluate the script in all browsers.

```
function addCode(code){
    var JS= document.createElement('script');
    JS.text= code;
    document.body.appendChild(JS);
}
```

**//test case**

```
var s= 'document.body.ondblclick=function(e){\n'+
'e=window.event? event.srcElement:e.target;\n'+
'alert(e.id || e.tagName);\n'+
'}\nalert("ready to double click!");';

addCode(s);
```

Comment: Works flawlessly when all other methods of injecting code to my pages (after loading) failed !!!

Comment: This works but does not fire the onload event for the script element.  I found eval to be more useful

Answer (score 5):

Using `innerHTML` will break if the text contains anything that can be interpreted as HTML such as `<`. It would be better to append one (or more) text nodes:

```
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
se.appendChild(document.createTextNode('alert(1)'));
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(se);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a script tag experience you could convert the javascript text into a Blob and then set the src property of the script tag to the blob url.